# How can I use gcm on web and phone

Tags: android

I want to develop a chat app on android and web.I don't want to use websockets for this.I will use gcm but how ?

User 1 on the web

User 2 on the android

Web to android or android to android is easy but how can I send a message to web from android using gcm ? What needs to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful info here:

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: I need more specific examples.Example:On the web what should I do ?

Comment: here is a link for web: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessaging my advice start with a small example

Comment: Is it for only chrome ?

Comment: It is looking a extension writing tutorial for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

you will have a common web server. use something like ajax for web chat interface and use GCM for the client.

Be it GCM on device or ajax on web page all are http/https calls. All you need is on diffrentiator to identify where the user is chatting from web or device. Just google the relevant terms and you will have what you want. I suggest start from database and server side REST APIs.

Comment: I need a xmpp server ?

Comment: that's your pick. where are you gonna store all your data? like user id, registration id, chat history etc?

Comment: How is whatsapp doing this ? They are using gcm for all messages ? Do you know anything about this ?

Comment: they use GCM to send only meta data of chat... like "john is typing or the double tick marks or the blue color of a chat" and they probably use android service to download media. but as described in the GCM documentation, you can use gcm to send complete chat text itself 4KB is sufficient enough.

Comment: Do you know what they are using for send/receive chat text ?